# sed replace regular expression match

Tags: regex, replace, sed, match

Portion of my dataset which is pipe delimited csv file:

```
|B20005G |77|B20005G 077|$2,500 to $4,999|
|B20005G |78|B20005G 078|$5,000 to $7,499|
|B20005G |79|B20005G 079|$7,500 to $9,999|
```

I match the lines of the third field with this sed expression:

```
sed -n '/|[[:alnum:]]\{7\} [[:digit:]]\{3\}|/p'
```

Now, is there a way to tell sed to delete space in the third field to get this:

```
|B20005G |77|B20005G077|$2,500 to $4,999|
|B20005G |78|B20005G078|$5,000 to $7,499|
|B20005G |79|B20005G079|$7,500 to $9,999|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a regex like this

```
\([[:alnum:]]{7}\) \([[:digit:]]{3}\)
```

defines two groups, the ones between `\( \)`, which we can refer to in the substitution via `\1`, `\2`, so

```
sed -n 's/\([[:alnum:]]\{7\}\) \([[:digit:]]\{3\}\)/\1\2/' myfile.txt
```

which gets rid of the space in between the two groups.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `awk` method

```
awk -F'|' 'BEGIN {OFS="|"} {sub(/ +/,"",$4)}1' FileName
```

**OutPut:**

```
|B20005G |77|B20005G077|$2,500 to $4,999|
|B20005G |78|B20005G078|$5,000 to $7,499|
|B20005G |79|B20005G079|$7,500 to $9,999|
```

Comment: Thank you for the elegant awk solution!